# FFMPEG video merging. Only first video shows

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg

I'm trying to put 7 second intro video before another one, but I keep having trouble with it. I don't need to do anything else then add intros to videos.

This is what I'm currently getting.

```
(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4





    C:\Users\Business>cd desktop

C:\Users\Business\Desktop>cd testfile

C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Testfile>(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt

C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Testfile>
C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Testfile>(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt

C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Testfile>ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-93308-g1144d5c96d Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt  

libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000261c7072c00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.042667, bitrate: 2453 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2325 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 2325 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=110209 fps=3246 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1103461kB time=01:01:17.41 bitrate=2458.1kbits/s speed= 108x
video:1042171kB audio:57353kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.358030%

C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Testfile>
```

It shows the 7 second video as the whole video. Someway i got it to change after 7 seconds, but then the rest of the video was really buddy.

Comment: Show info for each input listed in `mylist.txt`, such as the complete output of `ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i main.mp4`. Each input must have the same parameters to concatenate properly.

Comment: I'm completely beginner. I don't understand anything of your post.How are the inputs different?

Comment: I don't know how your inputs are different. That's why I asked for the output from ffmpeg. If you just run a plain ffmpeg command it will output info about each input. Then I can look at the info to see what ffmpeg says about each input and determine the different parameters.

Comment: oh, heres the results of mylist: file 'testvideo.mp4'
file 'testvideo1.mp4'

Comment: I wanted the info for the files listed in `mylist.txt`. Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -i testvideo1.mp4`. You can [edit] your question to add this info.

Comment: Try removing the `-c copy` and let ffmpeg re-encode the videos. That might help narrow down where the problem lies. It could be the codec's don't merge nicely when concatenated.

Comment: "If you just run a plain ffmpeg command it will output info about each input."

What is plain ffmpeg command?

Comment: @JamesAshworth Didn't get a notification of your reply (you need to use @llogan). By "plain command" I meant: `ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -i testvideo1.mp4`